# std:sort vs inserting into an std::set

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, set, std

I am reading some line segments from cin. Each line segment is represented by a start and end point. 2D. X and Y.

The input is not sorted. It is in random order. (Update:But I need them sorted first by X and then by Y)

I can read in all the segments, store them in a vector and then call std::sort. On the other hand, I can create an empty std::set and insert each segment as it arrives. The set will automatically maintain sorted order. Which of the two approaches is more efficient?

Update: The total size of the input (number of segments) is known in advance.

Comment: @larsmans thanks for correction. Posting from a bar. ;)

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Real-world performance data > "what some guy on the internets told me"

Comment: @jalf I thought this was an old question with a generally accepted answer. Also, how many different input sets should I try before reaching a decision?

Comment: You should try with input sets that match the ones you're actually going to use. So you know how it performs **in your case**

Comment: @AgnelKurian: That's... sad...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what is? Posting from a bar?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually, I agree. What is really sad is that I have no choice. Deadlines suck.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should measure the performance of both approaches to be sure, but it's a safe bet to assume that `std::sort` on an `std::vector` is *way* faster than inserting into an `std::set` due to locality effects and the large constants hiding in the tree insertion algorithm. Also, the subsequent lookups and iteration will be faster.

(However, `std::set` is better suited for supporting a mixed series of insertions and deletions/lookups/iterations. Maintaining order in vector is expensive, as each insertion will take linear time on average.)

Comment: Oh, really? Why's that then?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the constants in tree insertion are pretty high (think rebalancing in a red-black tree) compared to those in a well-optimized sort.

Answer (score 13):

As a good rule of thumb, the stricter guarantees are offered, the worse performance you'll get.

Inserting into a `std::set` guarantees that the sequence is sorted *after every insertion*.

Inserting into a `std::vector`, and calling `std::sort` *once* after all insertions have been done guarantees that the sequence is sorted once all manipulations on the `vector` have been done. It doesn't require the vector to be sorted during all the intermediate insertions.

A `std::vector` also exhibits better spatial locality, and requires fewer memory allocations.
So I would assume the `vector` approach to be faster, but if performance matters to you, then it matters enough to be *measured*.

If you don't care to measure what is faster **in your case** for **your** data sets with **your** code in **your** application, then you don't care which is faster.

Answer (score 4):

Use the container that has the appropriate semantics for your needs. Efficiency generally follows on automatically from that choice.

*If* you then experience performance bottlenecks, do some benchmarking.

Comment: My needs are that I should be able to traverse input from left to right. In case two inputs have the same x, lesser y wins.

Comment: @AgnelKurian If there is no inherent ordering to your data, use a set. It's a blob of stuff squeezed into a bag. As a pleasing side effect you get lexicographic (or whatever you need) ordering out of it when iterating, so if you want that at the end then that's handy too.

Answer (score 4):

It indeed does depend, but it's certain that `std::set` is intended for random inserts and deletes. In this case you are only inserting. Go with `std::vector`.
Also, perhaps more importantly, if you know beforehand how many segments there are, you only have to allocate the vector only once, it will not reallocate memory everytime it doubles in size.